# How do I access data that has been saved with Woocommerce WC Integration?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a settings page for my woocommerce theme with the [WC Integration Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/implementing-wc-integration/). But how I can access the the stored settings now? I can't find any information about that, or am I blind?

What I have figured out so far:

```
// in single product site
global $woocommerce;
print_r( $woocommerce );
```

I have found my settings as an array here:

`$woocommerce->integrations->integrations['integration-my_theme_name']->settings`

But I don't think this is the right way to get  the data. I guess there will be exists a function for that?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have found an **acceptable solution**:

```
$my_settings = get_option('woocommerce_{my-used-integration-id}_settings');
```

Where `{my-used-integration-id}` is the used `id` in your integration class.

---

**Example:**

Part of the integration class ([Implementing the WC Integration Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/implementing-wc-integration/)):

```
// Integration
class WC_Integration_Demo_Integration extends WC_Integration {

    public function __construct() {
        global $woocommerce;
        $this->id                 = 'foo-bar';

        ...
```

And then access this settings later:

```
$my_settings = get_option('woocommerce_foo-bar_settings');
```

Now `$my_settings` is an array which contains all your defined fields and values.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but as it comes up high in Google search I'm adding my solution:

The saved options can be accessed through the class.

```
$my_options = new WC_Integration_Demo_Integration();
$my_option = $my_options->get_option( 'your_option_name' );
```

No need to worry about arrays etc, all of that is handled by the WC_Integration class.